# Modal operators are not extensional

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I've read the following definition of an "extensional operator" in logic:

> By an
>   extensional operator
>   we mean any operator which allows us
>   to replace its arguments by equivalent elements.
>   Intensional
>   operators are those that are not extensional.

It is supposed to be clear that modal operators, such as

> $\square P \equiv $ it is neccessary that $P$

are intensional. However, I have a hard time seeing why. How do I find two equivalent arguments $P_1, P_2$ s.t. "it is necessary that $P_1$ and not "it is necessary that $P_2$"

I would appreciate an insight, it need not be too strict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to understand the [intensional nature of modal operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intension#Intensional_statement_form) ?

> Consider the statement "It is *possible* that Aristotle did not tutor Alexander the Great."
>
> And make the following substitutions: "Aristotle" $\to$ "the tutor of Alexander the Great".
>
> We have here two co-extensive expressions (i.e. two terms referring to the same object) such that one of them occurs in the statement, and if the other one is put in its place the result is a different statement with a different logical value (i.e. truth-value).
>
> > An intensional statement, then, is one such that the substitution of co-extensive terms fails to preserve logical value .

The same for "necessity".

See also [Modal logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/) and [Intensional logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intensional/#ProModLog).

Comment: I don't see how that makes any sense. If "Aristotle" and "the tutor of Alexander the Great" refer to the same object, then both sentences "It is possible that Aristotle did not tutor Alexander the Great" and "It is possible that the tutor of Alexander the Great did not tutor Alexander the Great" are equivalent; i.e. false

Comment: @Jytug - NO. "It is possible that the tutor of Alexander the Great did not tutor Alexander the Great" does not hold, because obviously there is no circumstance where the tutor of Alexander the Great did not tutor Alexander the Great. While "It is possible that Aristotle did not tutor Alexander the Great" does hold, because there is some "alternative" world (i.e. possible world) where Alexander has been tutored by e.g. Plato.

Comment: Oh, I see. So in the Kripke semantics "it's possible" means that there might be another state where the statement hold, but not in the current one

Comment: @Jytug - exactly. See [Kripke semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics#Basic_definitions) : "$ \Box A$ holds in world $w : w \Vdash \Box A$ if and only if $A$ holds in **every** world $u : u \Vdash A$ that is "accesible" from $w$" and  "$\Diamond A$ holds in world $w : w \Vdash \Diamond A$ iff $A$ holds in **some** world $u$ that is "accesible" from $w$".